# mapreduce for word frequency in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I want my python program to output a list of the top ten most frequently used words and their associated word count. I have to use mrjob - mapreduce to created this program. I wrote a program that finds the frequency of the words and outputs them in from most to least. However I'm not sure how to output only the top ten most frequently used words. I was thinking that maybe I could put it in a list and use a second map reducer for sorting, but I'm not sure how to do this with mapreduce. I new programming with mapreduce and python.
can someone give me any suggestions?

```html
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
import re

# Word frequency from book sorted by frequency
# File: book.txt  

# regular expression used to identify word
WORD_REGEXP = re.compile(r"[\w']+")

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def steps(self):
        # 2 steps
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_words,
                   reducer=self.reducer_count_words),
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_make_counts_key,
                   reducer=self.reducer_output_words)
        ]

    # Step 1
    def mapper_get_words(self, _, line):
        words = WORD_REGEXP.findall(line)
        for w in words:
            yield w.lower(), 1

    def reducer_count_words(self, word, values):
        yield word, sum(values)

    # Step 2
    def mapper_make_counts_key(self, word, count):
        # sort by values
        yield '%04d' % int(count), word

    def reducer_output_words(self, count, words):
        # First Column is the count
        # Second Column is the word
        for word in words:
            yield count, word


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an unordered collection of key, value.  One solution would be to convert to a list of tuples as you can still maintain the data association of word and count and simultaneously introduce indexing for sorting.
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts 
You can then slice off the first 10 for most common